# Uploaded file is corrupted using Azure DevOps API for creating attachments - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, azure, rest, file-handling, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to upload the user inputted file into Azure using their DevOps API for creating attachments which I can later on the link with the work items.

Using the following code, I tried to upload the binary content of the file in the request payload into Azure but when I try to view that file or download it, I am unable to read its content and it says that the file is corrupted. My assumption is that I am not able to create the right request payload. This function is called only when a file is added to the filepond component.

I have tested the file data on the online converter website. I don't know what I am doing wrong here as the request payload is correct.

Following link is the Microsoft documentation on their API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

```
  pondHandleAddFile(event: any) {
    this.disabled = false; 
    var self = this;
    this.myPond.getFiles().forEach(file => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      var files = file.file;
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsBinaryString(files);
      reader.onload = function () {
        const upload$ = self.http.post<any>(`https://dev.azure.com/COMPANY_NAME/_apis/wit/attachments?api-version=6.0&fileName=${file.file.name}`, { 'body': (<String>reader.result) },
          {
            headers: {
              "Authorization": "Basic AUTH_TOKEN",
              'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            }
          }).subscribe((res) => {
            console.log(res)
            self.attachmentURLS.push(res.url);
            self.disabled = false;
          });
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: You can refer to [Uploading attachments using REST API v5.1 to AzureDevOps work items isn't working anymore](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/uploading-attachments-using-rest-api-v51-to-azured/914089) and [Attachments Created via API cannot be viewed correctly/corrupted file](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues/211)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT The first link is for C# and the second one is someone having trouble with Microsoft Flow. They don't answer my question but they do mention the lack of documentation. If you can post a JS code snippet then that might be helpful. Or tell me whats wrong with mine. I would be deeply grateful if you will. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you have already started an issue on GitHub, posting the link here to help other community members: [Uploaded file is corrupted using Azure DevOps API for creating attachments - JavaScript](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues/510)

Comment: That also hasn't been answered yet, please answer at your earliest convenience. A code snipped uploading an image file or pdf file to Azure as an attachment.

Comment: You can also ask this question on [azure-devops-node-api](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api/issues) or [Azure Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem)